# выборка объектов массива по параметру объекта

Tags: java, android, коллекции

Есть `List<Object>`, в объектах есть параметры, значение параметров бывает повторяется.

Как сделать выборку по одному из параметров, для того чтобы добавить в новый `List<Object>` с  параметрами без повторений?

Допустим выборка по параметру `catalog`.

```
list.add(new Object(№1,name1,catalog1);
list.add(new Object(№2,name2,catalog5); 
list.add(new Object(№3,name1,catalog1);
list.add(new Object(№4,name4,catalog3);
```

`newlist` должен содержать объекты под номером 1,2,4

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class DirectLab {
    private static DirectLab sDirectLab;
    private List<Direct> mDirects;

    public static DirectLab get(Context context) {
        if (sDirectLab == null) {sDirectLab = new DirectLab(context);}
        return sDirectLab;
    }

    private DirectLab(Context context) {
        mDirects = new ArrayList<>();
        mDirects.add(new 
        Direct(name:"Болт",name_directory:"Метизы",directory:"m16x40"));
        mDirects.add(new Direct("Шпилька","Метизы","m12"));
        mDirects.add(new Direct("Болт","Метизы","m6x80"));  
        mDirects.add(new Direct("Кабель","Электрика","6кв"));
        mDirects.add(new Direct("Щиток","Электрика","30х40см"));
    }


    public List<Direct> getDirects() {
        return mDirects;
    }

    public List<Direct> getCatalog(List<Direct> unicum ){
        List<Direct> catalog = new ArrayList<>();
        /**
         *как добавить объекты в catalog c не повторяющимся параметром 
         *name_directory
         */ 

        return catalog;
    }
}
```

Вся эта песня реализуется в android studio, `getCatalog` мне нужен для того, что бы вывести в `recycler.view` названия каталогов, следующий шаг будет кликнув по каталогу, выводить список объектов в которых прописан этот каталог

Comment: По какому признаку должны выбираться именно эти объекты?

Comment: объекты в newlist должны быть с уникальным параметром catalog#, в процессе выборки не важно какой из объектов попадет в newlist под №1 или под №3, главное что бы объект с параметром catalog1 был в единственном экземпляре в newliste

Comment: Масса вариантов. Например, переопределяете метод `hashCode()` у объектов, и перекладываете все ообъекты в HashSet. HashSet хранит только уникальные объекты.

Comment: Ну вот, нормальный вопрос и сразу же нормальные ответы, так держать :)

Answer (score 1):

Просто напишите метод, который будет сравнивать объекты по полям. Например:

```
    class Object {
        private String name;

        private String catalog;

        public Object(String name, String catalog) {
            this.name = name;
            this.catalog = catalog;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Object o1 = new Object("name1", "catalog1");
            Object o2 = new Object("name2", "catalog1");

            System.out.println(o1.compare(o2));
        }

        public int compare(Object o) {
            if (this.name.compareTo(o.getName()) != 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (this.catalog.compareTo(o.getName()) != 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getCatalog() {
            return this.catalog;
        }
    }
```

Потом можно перебором сравнивать объекты из коллекции с объектом, который хотите добавить. Этот метод позволит включить несколько полей в сравнение, и при любом совпадении объект не будет добавлен в колллекцию (на это уже нужна отдельная проверка в самом цикле).

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<Object, Object> hash = mew HashMap<>();

list.forEach(object -> hash.put(object.catalog, object));
hash.values().forEach(object -> newlist.add(object));
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вот так :

```
public static List<String> getCatName(DirectLab directLab) { //возвращает уникальные названия категорий
    dir = new HashSet<>();
    for (Direct d : directLab.getDirects()) {
        dir.add(d.getName_directory());
    }
    catName = new ArrayList<>(dir);
    return catName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задачу можно довольно удобно решить с использованием [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava):

```
    /*получаем из списка Observable*/
    Observable<Direct> observableDirect = Observable.fromIterable(directLab.getDirects());
    /*группируем, например по Name_directory*/
    Observable<GroupedObservable<String, Direct>> groupedObservable = observableDirect
      .groupBy(direct -> direct.getName_directory());

    /*Далее можете уже работать с группированным Observable, фильтровать, преобразовывать и т.д.*/
    /*например получить названия групп*/
    List<String> catalogNames = new ArrayList<>();  
    groupedObservable
      .subscribe(group -> catalogNames.add(group.getKey()));     

    /*получить объекты определенной группы*/     
    List<Direct> catalogDirects = new ArrayList<>();
    groupedObservable
      .filter(group -> group.getKey().equals("название группы"))
      .subscribe(group -> group.subscribe( direct -> catalogDirects.add(direct) ) )
```